# Unique Values in Excel by ID Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I'm guessing this is relatively straight forward, but I can't quite figure it out or find a similar post that resolves this issue.

I basically want to understand the unique values in Column B for each unique ID in Column A

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ID 1 | Cat 1 |
| ID 1 | Cat 2 |
| ID 1 | Cat 2 |
| ID 2 | Cat 1 |
| ID 2 | Cat 1 |
| ID 2 | Cat 3 |
| ID 3 | Cat 1 |

What I would like to do is remove the duplicates from Column B per each unique ID in Column A.  Based on the above example, I'd like the output to be as follows:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| ID 1 | Cat 1 |
| ID 1 | Cat 2 |
| ID 2 | Cat 1 |
| ID 2 | Cat 3 |
| ID 3 | Cat 1 |

Does any have any suggestions for an Excel formula?

I tried 'removing duplicates' but this does not quite get the result I was hoping for.

Comment: Welcome. You may use Pivot Tables for this easily.Google for it

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this formula:

=UNIQUE(range)

Answer (score 2):

"Removing duplicates" got the expected result on my end. Did you deselect any of the columns for the comparison?

Correct result:
[image]

If you deselect either Column there, you'd get the wrong result.

Or use `UNIQUE(A1:B8)`
[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it would be something ridiculous my end.  Appreciate everyone's response. :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting as an alternative solution to those who don't have access to **`MS365`** also I see OP has tagged **`Excel 2016`** therefore using <kbd>INDEX()</kbd> with <kbd>AGGREGATE()</kbd> along with <kbd>FREQUENCY()</kbd> function the ****Unique Values in Excel by ID Number**** can be accomplished, though it is simple with <kbd>UNIQUE()</kbd> Function only for those using Modern Versions of Excel Aka **`Excel 2021`** or **`MS365`**.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$8,
 AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$B$8)-ROW($A$2)+1)/
 (FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$8&"|"&$B$2:$B$8<>"",
 MATCH("~"&$A$2:$A$8&"|"&$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8&"|"&$B$2:$B$8&"",0)),
 ROW($A$2:$B$8)-ROW($A$2)+1)>0),ROWS(D$1:D1)),COLUMNS($D1:D1)),"")
```

---

Formula needs to be filled down and filled right ! Formulas works with **`Excel 2010+`** onwards !!

---

Also, quite easy to do with <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>

[image]

---